# React native tab view, Press to switch tab doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabview, react-native-tab-view

I'm using the package "react-native-tab-view" in my app.
To switch tab the swipe event is working really fine, but when I press the tab I want to go, it doesn't work, I don't know why... This is my component :

```
export default function TabsMenu() {


const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    {key: 'env', title: 'Env.'},
    {key: 'imp', title: 'Imp.'},
    {key: 'suppl', title: 'Suppl.'},
    {key: 'menus', title: 'Menus.'},
  ]);

  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    env: Environnement,
    imp: Impression,
    suppl: Supplements,
    menus: Menus,
  });

  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{index, routes}}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      renderTabBar={props => (
        <TabBar
          {...props}
          renderLabel={this._renderLabel}
          getLabelText={({route: {title}}) => title}
          indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
          tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
          style={styles.tab}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

The views used for the routes are just : 
- Form with some inputs
- And the "Menus" one, is a "DraggableFlastList", I tried to remove it, and the tab "Press" event still doesn't work...

By the way, my DraggableFlastList prevents me to swipe left/right on my tabs, (because of TouchableOpacity element I guess), so I am really stuck when I am on the tab "Menus"...

If you guys got a solution... :)

Comment: Did you tried using onTabPress function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use onTabPress props like this :

```
<TabBar
  onTabPress={({ route, preventDefault }) => {
    if (route.key === 'home') {
      preventDefault();

      // Do something else
    }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

and also check TabView other props is here: 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
 <TabBar
  {...props}
  scrollEnabled
  renderLabel={this.renderLabel}
  onTabLongPress={(scene) => {
    const { route } = scene
    props.jumpTo(route.key)
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it work , and what was the issue to make your answer more usefull

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are **not in a debug mode**, on tap functionality doesn't work when debug mode is on. I faced the same issue, stop debugging solve my problem.

In my case, swipe functionality was working fine but not tap! Found this thread on github [Tab bar does not respond to taps](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/703) and solved my issue finally. Hope this will help others who are facing the same problem.

If you face the same problem, I suggest to check in real device.